# Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView error for school

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this problem of my app not executing and I do not know what is causing it. I know that it is from my Main Activity file but I have nothing in there. This is the only reason that my app can not work in the emulator for Android studio in lollipop. I really need help for school.

**This is the error:**

```
02-01 08:23:59.750 3926-3926/com.shifanh.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.shifanh.app, PID: 3926
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shifanh.app/com.shifanh.app.HomeDahboard}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
   at com.shifanh.app.HomeDahboard.onCreate(HomeDahboard.kt:10)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.shifanh.app:drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" (7f070064)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070064 a=-1 r=0x7f070064}
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
   at com.shifanh.app.HomeDahboard.onCreate(HomeDahboard.kt:10) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
   02-01 
   08:23:59.751 
   1495-
1573/system_process 
W/ActivityManager:   
Force 
finishing activity 
1 
com.shifanh.app/.HomeDahboard
```

**This is the code for HomeDahboard.kt:**

```
    package com.shifanh.app

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle

    class HomeDahboard : AppCompatActivity() {

         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_dahboard)   
         }
    }
```

**This is my layout.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shifanh.app.HomeDahboard"
    android:background="#fcfcfc">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="App Title"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:background="@drawable/materialbackground">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.demotxt.droidsrce.homedashboard.Home"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#fcfcfc"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/ll">
            <LinearLayout
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/bankcardId"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/cercleshape"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                            android:padding="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Banking"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Check your bank activities"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/cercleshape"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                            android:padding="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Ideas"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Check your bank activities"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/cercleshape"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                            android:padding="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Add"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Check your bank activities"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/cercleshape"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Links"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Check your bank activities"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="340dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/cercleshape"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                            android:padding="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Add"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Check your bank activities"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please post your layout xml

Comment: I posted the layout.xml

Answer (score 1):

In your ImageView

> android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"

this drawable maybe in `res -> drawable-v24` generated by Android Studio,
and only could be used in Android N

Comment: this is really solve my problem, and the very correct solution.
so it is better to have 2 drawable both image for v24 and < v24

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_white_24dp"
```

Instead of `android:src` because you are using vector drawable.

And your image is not in the folder of drawable, it is in the drawable v4, so you have to keep the image in drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Resources$NotFoundException**: Resource "com.shifanh.app:drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" (7f070064) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070064 a=-1 r=0x7f070064}

means the **ic_launcher_foreground** file doesn't exist in the expected drawable folder. Place it in `drawable-v21` as well